# problem with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i saw that android 2,3 is ready so i tried to install it in my eclipse.Firstly,i went to "Android SDK and AVD manager" in my installed packages and i updated them all.Secondly, i went from help to check for updates,i was waiting eclipse to download them and finally i restarted my eclipse!my problem is that all my old apps are not playing now and they have a red x in the package explorer.i wrote a helloWorld app in 2,3 android and its playing but as i try to run my old apps ,eclipse says that i have error in my code.please help,i m confused!!:)

Comment: also i can see an error in the console saying "Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:5'"

Comment: What's with using commas instead of decimal places? It makes no sense. There should be exactly 1 decimal in a number, just as there is exactly 1 period in a sentence.

Comment: Sigh.  In many areas of the world (outside Arizona), decimal commas are used in place of decimal points.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have your R.java in the gen/ folder ?

I got similar issue with new compiler in SDK 2.3, R.java sometimes disapears !

I manage to fix this by restarting eclipse and/or performing a clean in the projects.

Comment: yes i have the R.java.The package explorer has the red x,but as i open the java files i cant see any x and before i install the 2,3 they were running...

Comment: i clean all my projects and now they are running!!thanks VERY much for your idea,i didnt think to clean them...any idea why i had to clean the projects?pff

Comment: Actually no, I'm not very pleased with the new version of ADT included in SDK 2.3. It seems to be very bugged...